# getting error "only static members can be accessed in initializers"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
final pdf = pw.Document();
final image = PdfImage.file(pdf.document,bytes: File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync(),);
```

In the above code I am getting error on pdf.document parameter "only static members can be accessed in initializers" can you help me with a fix?

Comment: Well, in line 4 you can not reference pdf, when it is not static. Can you share some more code?

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: first of all, what is that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

objects are created at run-time thus also there fields, you can't have a instance field initialized in the class (where the object has not been created yet), so you need to make it a class field by making it `static`, if you want it as an instance field then initialize it in the constructor or in a instance method.